# Cross Comparing values between two columns for voting purposes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

**The current content of our Google sheet, is formatted as such:**

```
- PERSON 1 | PERSON 2 | YES
- PERSON 1 | PERSON 3 | YES
- PERSON 2 | PERSON 1 | YES
- PERSON 2 | PERSON 3 | YES
- PERSON 3 | PERSON 1 | NO
- PERSON 3 | PERSON 2 | NO
```

**and we need our content formatted as such:**

```
- _________| PERSON 1 | PERSON 2 | PERSON 3 |
- PERSON 1 |   X      |   YES    |    YES   |
- PERSON 2 |   YES    |   X      |    YES   |
- PERSON 3 |   NO     |   NO     |    X     |
```

Is there a simple way to do this using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"";   UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")})},
           {TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}));IFERROR({
              VLOOKUP(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),
 FILTER(A:C,B:B=INDEX(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),1,1)),3,0),
              VLOOKUP(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),
 FILTER(A:C,B:B=INDEX(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),2,1)),3,0),
              VLOOKUP(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),
 FILTER(A:C,B:B=INDEX(UNIQUE({FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")}),3,1)),3,0)},
 "X")}})
```

[image: 0]